# Java GUI different pages in different classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, repaint

I have a question about JFrame.
This is an Example of a Code of I refresh the JFrame and change from page 1 to page 2.
I remove the wrong components and the i add the right components. In a big code this will be very confusing what to add and what to remove.

```
package test;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        GUI g = new GUI();
    }
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField page1;
    JTextField page1Text;
    JTextField page2;
    JTextField page2Text;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    public GUI(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        page1 = new JTextField("Page 1");
        page1.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 50);

        page1Text = new JTextField("Text 1");
        page1Text.setBounds(20, 80, 100, 50);

        page2 = new JTextField("Page 2");
        page2.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 50);

        page2Text = new JTextField("Text 2");
        page2Text.setBounds(20, 80, 100, 50);

        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button1.setBounds(20, 200, 100, 50);

        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button2.setBounds(130, 200, 100, 50);

        frame.add(page1);
        frame.add(page1Text);
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);
        button2.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class ActionHandler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == button1){
                frame.remove(page2);
                frame.remove(page2Text);
                frame.add(page1);
                frame.add(page1Text);
                frame.repaint();
            }
            else if (event.getSource() == button2){
                frame.remove(page1);
                frame.remove(page1Text);
                frame.add(page2);
                frame.add(page2Text);
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a page in a different class or constructor or file and save it as for example page_1. And then in the ActionHandler i write

```
if (event.getSource() == button1){
    page_1();
    frame.repaint();
}
```

so that the frame has the right Components of page 1 in the right space.

Comment: You'd better use a `CardLayout` for this, see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet sounds like it would be to have each page in a separate class as a jpanel,design your panel accordingly and based on the human input, show/hide these panels on your content pane